# AS3 make an array of movieclip moves constantly. (this array constantly increases in size)

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

ActionScript 3.0

I got this bullet_array. 
and it pushes new bullet everytime I pressed spacebar. 
There's this "for loop", which works - only when I pressed spacebar. 
but I wanted the bullets to constantly move.

the 'for loop' is inside update(), which is from Event.ENTER_FRAME
so technically, the for loop should constantly be looping (i think), but it only went through ONCE, and only after the array increases in size. And it only worked on the new object, and didn't touch the old object.

```
     public function update(evt:Event = null)
    {
        stage.focus = stage;

        //fire = true is set by spacebar
        if (fire == true)
        {
            var snowball:MovieClip = new Snowball;
            snowball.x = (mcPlayer.x);
            snowball.y = (mcPlayer.y - 5); 
            snowballArray.push(snowball);
            SBAlength = +1; //stands for snowballArray's length
            addChild(snowball);
            fire = false; 

        }

        for (var i = SBAlength - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {

           snowballArray[i].y -= snowballSpd; //snowballSpd is already declared as 5
           for (var j = snowmanArray.length - 1; j>=0; j--)
           {
               for (var k = numberArray.length -1; k>0; k--)
               {
                   if     (snowballArray[i].hitTestObject(snowmanArray[j]))
                    {
                        if     (snowmanArray[j].hitTestObject(numberArray[k]))
                        {

                            bosslife -=  numberArray[k]; 
                            numberArray[k].splice(k,1); 

                        }
                        snowballArray[i].gotoAndPlay("hit");                
                        snowmanArray[j].splice(j,1); 
                        break;
                    }
                    if(numberArray[k] >= 0) 
                    {
                        numberArray[k].splice(k,1);

                        randomNo= Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1))+min;
                        numberArray[k].push(randomNo); 
                    }
                    snowmanArray[j].txtNumber.text = numberArray[j]; 
               }

           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other issues here, but:

**Maintaining the array length**

```
SBAlength = +1; // Sets your length to 1
```

Instead use:

```
SBAlength += 1; // Increases your length by 1
```

But really, you might as well use the array's `length` property in the loop, instead of maintaining `SBALength` (and risking it getting out of sync due to some future code):

```
for (var i = snowballArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

**Manipulating arrays**

Also (don't think this is related to your problem, but it will certainly cause errors), in your inner loop, you're constantly doing things like this:

```
snowmanArray[j].splice(j,1);
numberArray[k].push(randomNo);
// etc.
```

That would only work if the items in `numberArray` and `snowmanArray` are themselves arrays - not sure if they are, but doesn't seem like it, since you're also using the items as numbers:

```
bosslife -= numberArray[k];
```

The first statement is asking to remove an item *from an array stored in* `snowmanArray[j]` - not removing an item from `snowmanArray` itself. If you want to remove an item from `snowmanArray`, you'd do `snowmanArray.splice(j, 1)`.

In the same way, to add an item to `numberArray`, you'd do `numberArray.push(randomNo)`, rather than `numberArray[k].push(randomNo)`.

**Manipulating arrays inside loops etc.**

It's fine to e.g. remove the current array item while iterating over that array - but only as long as you do it in the way you do, starting from the end and going backwards. However...

After doing (or rather, intending to do) this if the snowman was hit:

```
snowmanArray.splice(j,1);
```

... you're later doing:

```
snowmanArray[j].txtNumber.text = numberArray[j];
```

I.e. you remove the snowman from the array, but then later on, you try to get the array item you just removed. You need to be sure that `snowmanArray[j]` still exists before you address it.

**Array item types**

You're mostly using `numberArray` as an array of `int` (or `Number`). Except here:

```
snowmanArray[j].hitTestObject(numberArray[k])
```

You can't hitTestObject against an `int`/`Number`. Not sure what the line is supposed to do, but the object you hit test against needs to be a `DisplayObject` (e.g. a `MovieClip`).

Comment: okk.. 

but... the code was like this previously. and since it wasn't looping through it, but only went through it once, and only on the newest snowball, so I thought maybe the snowballArray.length wasn't updating, and so, i place it there, and it still didn't work though... ... 

instead of debugging, i'm thinking maybe it's faster for you guys to teach me to make the codes to do these : 
snowballs constantly moving up, and is created only when spacebar is pressed.

Comment: `snowballArray.length` will always reflect the number of items in `snowballArray`. So if the outermost loop isn't being executed, that means there are no items in `snowballArray`. Do a `trace(snowballArray.length)` before the loop - you may be resetting the array elsewhere. Teaching "how to code this" is outside the scope of stackoverflow.

Comment: when i trace(snowballArray.length), i go this : 
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at snowFight/update()

and when i traced SBAlength, it was always 1. if i change the code from  = +1 to +=1, it became 0. why ?

Comment: oh... ... i'll try changing the codes again.   the numberArray is supposed to be numbers that display a text inside snowman movieclip,

Comment: "A term is undefined and has no properties" means `snowballArray` doesn't exist, so you can't get the property `snowballArray.length`. In other words, it's being thrown out elsewhere in the code - like you (somewhat) say in your own answer.

Comment: erm... for the arrays, after splicing it, shld i use break; or do a if(array[i] != null) ?

Comment: Must admit, at the moment I'm confused about what `numberArray` is used for, in combination with the amount of nested loops. But checking for null at least ensures you won't be accessing snowmen that have been disposed of.

Answer (score 0):

Erm...  after lots of tracing around and stuff, 
i figure that the main problem isn't with the array nor the splicing (though my codes is wrong -but it didn't work even if i commented away those codes), but that i place > instead of < to check bosslife, so it keep resetting the level, so snowballArray keeps becoming a new Array, hence the array.length didn't work, and using SBAlength gives some kinda weird error while inside the for loop.

Comment: SBAlength will "give an error", because your new array is empty, but you're accessing it as if it has `SBAlength` items - so you'll be trying to get array items which no longer exist.

Comment: yea, i know.. i sorta realise that after tracing around and seeing how the array constantly became 0 after becoming 1 once.  so i continued tracing around, thinking that i was splicing everything out, but even after commenting all the 'splice' things out, it didn't work, so i looked for those that reset the array. and i finally found out why...